# Iterating radially through a numpy array and caculating the variance by radial shells in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to calculate the numpy.var(array), however, I want a set of variance values instead of the variance of the entire array. The idea is to generate a bunch of evenly spaced circular shells from my numpy array and find the variance of each shell.

```
#For instance- a simple example: 

import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)

### Insert some method to find all of the values at each respective radius
```

RESULT

```
arr_radius_0 = [4]

arr_radius_1 = [0,1,2,5,8,7,6,3]

var_r0 = np.var(arr_radius_0)

var_r1 = np.var(arr_radius_1)
```

After getting all the variances for each respective shell, I want to append them all to a new array. The goal is to be able to calculate the radial variance for large data sets. I've been sweating over this for quite some time! Any help at all is super appreciated!

Comment: how do you want to split up the shells? Do you want a new shell for every single different radius, or do you want shells that enclose say, a < radius < b?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you wondering how to calculate the `np.var` over axes, or how to `np.concatenate` the different result arrays? Or something else?

Comment: I'm looking to calculate the np.var at each respective shell. I would set it up to calculate the variance where the radius of the circle = 1, then the variance of the next circle with radius = 2 and so on and so forth. In this way, I would calculate the np.var over multiple different axes. (each axes represented by newly the generated circle shell)